# WebComponents/Polymer - Lifecycle Callback Ordering in Trees

Tags: polymer, web-component

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<my-element-one>
    <my-element-two>
        <my-element-three></my-element-three>
    </my-element-two>
</my-element-one>
```

Now, let's say this was parsed into a DocumentFragment. Now, I then insert the fragment into the Document. What order will the attachedCallbacks of these custom elements fire? Will they consistently fire depth first (three, two, one)? Or will they fire from top to bottom (one, two, three)? Or is it entirely undetermined? If I remove the entire tree later, what order will the detachedCallbacks fire?

Finally, is this behavior consistent between the polyfill and the W3C spec's intended behavior? I've read through a bunch of the spec and haven't found a clear explanation on how this ordering should play out.

Comment: Here's a pointer towards the answer in the ongoing spec, though I'll admit that I haven't yet been able to piece out the answer to your question is from it: http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-lifecycle

Comment: Elements are upgraded in document order. This was to make .cloneNoe and .innerHTML consistent. There' ssome explanation and additional links here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/polymer-dev/McqYyQYrge0/discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I assume your original question is about Custom Elements in general, I've put together an example using Polymer which tries to replicate the tree ordering you're interested  in:

http://jsbin.com/yisaqe/3/edit

[image]

In this case, we see that the lifecycle callbacks are executed from top to bottom (one, two, three) rather than depth first (three, two, one):

If you remove the entire tree later on, the detached callbacks are similarly executed in a top to bottom order (one, two, three - see console)

http://jsbin.com/mejija/1/edit

[image]

I assume that this is consistent between the polyfill and the spec's intended behaviour, but I haven't been able to ascertain from the spec whether this is meant to differ. I hope that at least these proof of concepts are useful.

Comment: Thanks Addy. If you happen to come across something in the spec that specifically states that this is the behavior, please share. Otherwise, perhaps we should talk to the spec authors and have this point clarified.